# 1 little error in my transition coding

Tags: iphone, objective-c

[http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/2554/screenshot20090910at154.png http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/2554/screenshot20090910at154.png](http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/2554/screenshot20090910at154.png)
[Full Size Image](http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/2554/screenshot20090910at154.png)

Here you can see the code for the transition but it says there is an error before the "for"

What is it that i'm missing?

I basically want to do a fade in between images.

---

**EDIT**

Here is the updated code with the adjustments. I am still getting that error.

[http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/7978/screenshot20090910at102.png http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/7978/screenshot20090910at102.png](http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/7978/screenshot20090910at102.png)
[Updated Code](http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/7978/screenshot20090910at102.png)

The *NSArray** *theImages* line ends with the following

```
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"image10.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image11.jpg"], nil]];
```

Comment: In Xcode 3.1 (what you're using), the error bubbles appear after the error, not before.  One of the nice usability improvements in Xcode 3.2 causes the exact line with the error to be highlighted.

Answer (score 9):

The line before the `for` should read something like:

```
NSArray* theImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[...], // object 1
                                               ...,   // more objects
                                               [...], // object N
                                               nil]]; // nil must be last
```

Updated:

The error you are getting now is not the same as the one before. You'll need to look at more of your code in order to figure out what the error is referring to.

Also, can you post some of the code directly in your question instead of posting a picture? The font SO uses is easier to read than the one in the screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language it is, but I beleave this line should end with `];` instead of `,`

Answer (score 0):

Your issues seem to be simple syntactical ones.

There is one caused by these two lines (can't see above it to see where the issue is

```
}
{
```

Also, you have a new issue with the NSArray* Definition because you have

```
NSArray* theImages]; = .....
                  ^^This will cause an issue after you take care of the first one
```